# Sharpen image with scipy convolve2d - odd results

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to use the convolve2d function from scipy for sharpening a RGB image. The code is shown below. For convolution, I am using the sharpen kernel from wikipedia:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)

The output looks odd. I'm not sure what is incorrect here. I have experimented with changing data types of the array, it has given me some odd images.
'''

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("1.jpg")
img_array = np.array(image)


def RGB_convolve(image,kern):
    image2 = np.empty_like(image)
    for dim in range(image.shape[-1]):
        image2[:,:,dim]=convolve2d(image[:,:,dim],kern, 'same')
    return image2

KERNEL_sharpen = np.array([[0,-1,0],[-1,5,-1],[0,-1,0]])
im_filtered = RGB_convolve(img_array,KERNEL_sharpen)

output_image = Image.fromarray(im_filtered)
display(output_image)
```

'''
[In/Out Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTERG.png)

Update: [Image output after using Adrien Mau's suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ3KQ.png)

Comment: what is the dtype of 'img_array'? have you tried converting to float and changing the dynamic range to [0,1] after the convolution? if 'img_array' is uint8, than you might be saturating some of the pixel channles or overflowing them. not sure if overflowi is a possibility in numpy though.

Comment: I have tried changing data type on normalizing on one of my own RGB images but it gives strange results as aa03 found. Even starting and ending with float types, renormalizing ... didn't help
 I'm pretty sure this is due to the kernel being able to give out of range values ( -4*255 at minimum, 5*255 at maximum...). Normalizing it afterwards kills the dynamic of the image.

Comment: @yannziselman I have tried converting it to float. I'm just guessing at this point and converting between the dtypes. What do you mean by 'changing the dynamic range to [0,1] after the convolution?' How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are seeing some value overthrow.
I do not understand exactly why this works, but dividing the kernel by 255 and setting the initial image as a float yielded the correct result :

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import scipy.signal
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

f = "C:/Users/Ordi Calcul/Desktop/Capture.PNG"
image = Image.open( f )
img_array = np.array(image).astype('float')


def RGB_convolve(image,kern):
    image2 = np.empty_like(image)
    for dim in range(image.shape[-1]):
        image2[:,:,dim]=convolve2d(image[:,:,dim],kern, 'same')
    return image2

KERNEL_sharpen = np.array([[0,-1,0],[-1,5,-1],[0,-1,0]]) / 255
im_filtered = RGB_convolve(img_array,KERNEL_sharpen)


plt.figure( figsize=(10,4))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow( image )
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow( im_filtered )
```

With Image you would do:

```
output_image = Image.fromarray(im_filtered.astype('uint8'))
display(output_image)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work for me. See the updated image attached above with the original post

Comment: Well i also have issues with Image.fromarray and display.. But it should work with matplotlib's imshow ?
Again i think it's due to the values being able to go out of the [0,255] range with this filter. You can force negative and >255 value to go to 0 or 255 but this kills the contrast of the image.. i'm not sure there is a way that is better than other.